# Getting 403 access denied for bitbucket webhook to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I've configured a bitbucket webhook to trigger a jenkins build. The jenkins is running in a docker container hosted in a private cloud. I'm getting a 403 status code with access denied error when I view the results of the request in bitbucket. Not sure what the issue is because bitbucket is able to hit the endpoint, just that it's saying access denied. Not sure where I'm supposed to change such permissions so it can work.

Comment: Please add some logs for proper debugging

Comment: Please add some logs from your build

Comment: do you have ports forwarded to that container?

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Cloud cannot access your webhook if you are using localhost, this can only be accessed by the server where Jenkins is running in your local network. You will need to use the public IP address or domain name in the URL, instead of localhost.

Comment: this is not true